# Why modelVersion of pom.xml is necessary and always set to 4.0.0?

Tags: java, maven

I have noticed that Maven's `<modelVersion></modelVersion>` of `pom.xml` is always set to `4.0.0`.

Can you please help me understand what is the importance of this tag and why it should be set to `4.0.0`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It is always set to 4.0.0 in Maven 2 and 3, because, at present, there is no other model.

> Notice that `modelVersion` contains 4.0.0. That is currently the only supported POM version, and is always required. [[source](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#quick-overview)]

But it wouldn't necessarily *need* to always be set to 4.0.0 if there was another version of the model. A POM has to comply with a model. Let's say Maven 4 comes up with model 4.1. If you write your pom to comply with 4.1, it wouldn't be compatible with Maven 3 and model 4.0.0.

It's defined as a mandatory, possibly to enforce a specific XML model in case new models are defined.

Comment: LOL my app was on version 4 and I got an error while updating the version to 5!

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/POM+Model+Version+5.0.0

Comment: You didn't really explain in this answer why this tag is needed and what a model is.

Comment: Any idea why the `modelVersion` has `minOccurs` set to 0 in the Maven 4 XSD, if Maven can't run without it?

Answer (score 11):

model version is the version of project descriptor  your POM conforms to.
It needs to be included and is set.
The value 4.0.0 just indicated that it is compatible Maven 3.

Comment: What is a "project descriptor"?

Answer (score 6):

The Correct answer should be the combination of the answers by @Toumi and @Boj. Also have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/POM+Model+Version+5.0.0 for more background of this.

Comment: Well, this should have been a comment.

Answer (score 4):

**modelVersion** - containing the model version of the POM. 
Maven 1.x used a model which contained a 3.0.0 element as an immediate child of the root. 
Maven 2.x / 3.x has used a 4.0.0 element.

**version** - containing the version of the project. If this attribute is missing then the parent element must be present and the version will be inherited from the parent project.